# Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout. Release only

Tags: android

I've been developing a project for 2 months and it works in debug mode.
Today I created a release apk and I have an error on all devices:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/constraint/solver/widgets/ConstraintWidgetContainer;
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.constraint.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.constraint.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Please help!

```
'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0'
```

Comment: add multidex and invalidate caches / restart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

select **file** and choose invalidate **caches / restart**

if not worked then update it to

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

Comment: add this dependancy and invalidate restart

Answer (score 3):

To me it happens copying an existing class from a non androidx project into an androidx one. 
I had to change:

**android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout**

in the xml layout

into:

**androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout**

and it solved the issue.

Comment: I just plugged those into a text compare tool just to make sure... but they're both identical. To be clear... both of the bolded strings are the same.

Comment: yes... my bad... dyslexia is hunting me. The first should 'probably' be "android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout"

Answer (score 2):

I had to add multidex support:

**build.gradle:**

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
       ...
       multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

and:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

setting

```
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries false
}
```

solved the problem

Comment: try also invalidate caches / restart after that

Comment: I solved. I needed to change android:src to app:srcCompat. Tks